# Java pack of variables

Tags: java

Hello I want to make "something" in java that is a pack of boolean variables. Coming from C I would create a struct that holds these variables so they are organized somehow. Now in java I am confused on how I should move on. To be more specific I would like to know what is better for this occasion:

A class with private members  and getters-setters?

A class with static private members?

An interface with these values?

Thx in advance.

To be more specific I would like to pass a bunch of options to a function, so instead of calling a function like

```
foo(arg1,arg2,arg3.... argn); //each arg has different type
```

I want to create a pack of this args and call the function like this:

```
foo(packetOfArgs);
```

Can you provide me with any guidelines for this occasion?

Comment: It really really depends on *how* you are going to use this... At any rate it seems that none of the options you provided are correct, and you're looking for a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) instead. Then again, at a second read, I'm probably wrong... I can't tell whether you're looking for a general collection or a specific *thing* whose structure won't change. Former, you want a collection, latter, you want one of Java's collections.

Comment: A class is similar to a struct, so your first option is a possibility. But you could also use an array (`boolean boolArray[] = ...;`), or a `List`/`ArrayList` with the values you want. It really depends on what you want.

Comment: Use java.util.List: `List<Boolean> yourList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();` then `yourList.add(true);` etc...

Comment: You can use any collection, and accordingly you need to write code to extract it in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a variable number of arguments in java like this:

```
public void yourMethod(Object... arguments) {
    ...
}
```

With this method, you can pass any number of parameters of the same type. In the example above, I put as type `Object`, that means that it will take any class. You can specify primitive types as well

Take note that the variable arguments construct must be the last in your method, ex:

```
public void yourMethod(int someArgument, String... arguments) {
    ...
}
```

As you want to pass `boolean` primitives you can just say:

```
public void yourMethod(boolean... arguments) {
    ...
}
```

Now you treat `arguments` as an array. That means that you have the `length` attribute and all others.

Also, for your specific problem, where you want to have *a pack of boolean values* you can use the data structure called `BitSet`.

For the C++ implementation you can look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/).

For the Java implementation reference you can look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

The description of a BitSet is this:

> This class implements a vector of bits that grows as needed. Each
>   component of the bit set has a boolean value. The bits of a BitSet are
>   indexed by nonnegative integers. Individual indexed bits can be
>   examined, set, or cleared. One BitSet may be used to modify the
>   contents of another BitSet through logical AND, logical inclusive OR,
>   and logical exclusive OR operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, the most straight-forward solution that does not care about variable types.

```
public class VarHolder {

    private Object[] vars;

    public VarHolder(Object... vars)
    {
        this.vars = vars;
    }

    /**
     * Gets vars.
     * @return vars
     */
    public Object[] getVars()
    {
        return vars;
    }


}
```

It depends though on your requirements and if you are fine with no argument restriction and casting of variables later on which can be solved with something like this VarHolder's utility method with generics:

```
public <T> T getVar(int index, Class<T> clazz)
{
    return (T)vars[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you are going to use the values.

- If the different args need to be unique to objects, you could define a class with getters and setters.
- If the different args are not needed to be unique to objects, then you could use a class with static private members, or better yet just a list.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to a struct is a class with private members and getters and setters, as you named it in your first option.

This would be the way to go to encapsulate multiple variables into one object. Considering code design, those variables should fit together semantically. Read about cohesion. coupling and encapsulation in object oriented design.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class for storing your args and pass that in, or you could create an ArrayList of the args (provided they all extend a base class).

I would recommend a class. I believe that if the args are public you should be able to get and set without any getters or setters (though it's been a while since I've done Java). :)

```
PacketOfArgs packetOfArgs = new PacketOfArgs();

packetOfArgs.arg1 = 0;
packetOfArgs.arg2 = 1.5;
packetOfArgs.arg3 = "string";
packetOfArgs.arg4 = true;

foo(packetOfArgs);

class PacketOfArgs {

    public int arg1;
    public float arg2;
    public String arg3;
    public boolean arg4;

    PacketOfArgs() {

    }

}
```